# Dependency Property or a normal property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` and it contains a `Button`. Now, in some Windows I don't want to show this `Button`. To achieve this I see two options.

1. Create a DP.
2. Bind directly with the viewModel's property instead of creating DP.

Which of the above 2 options should be used?

**UPDATE:**

I found third way as well.

I am passing false in the CanCommandExecute of the binded Command which will make it's IsEnabled to false.

I am using IsEnabled with Visibility using Converter.

How abt this solution?

Comment: Having a property (no need for DP here, as long as your ViewModel is not a DependencyObject but an implementation for INotifyProperyChanged) for Visibility is the cleanest way. This can also call the CanExecute of your Button Command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should be the order of consideration
1. DP -> cleaner approach
2. If not DP, then CanCommandExecute -> Only purpose of this mechanism is to provide enable/disable support of Command handling
3. If not DP, CanCommandExecute, Normal property on VM (with BooleanToVisibilityConverter). This should not be preferred ( especially if there are multiple controls there are required to be enabled/disabled).

Answer (score 2):

Having a property IsVisible (no need for DP here, as long as your ViewModel is not a DependencyObject but an implementation for INotifyPropertyChanged) for Visibility is the cleanest way. This can also call the CanExecute of your Button Command. That way you express clearly that you want to change Visibility in some way, and Bind to that.

Comment: Its a UserControl without VIewModel.

Comment: ...but your view will have a viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a DP is more clean way of implementation and the later is quick and dirty method.

Answer (score 1):

CanCommandExecute will be the best solution for this as it will me more clean and also it will be having less number of c# code..